# Multiple bwspec for BoxWhiskerChart

Tags: plotting

If I want to make a horizontal boxplot (with outliers) for y:

```
y = {5.5, 5.61, 4.88, 5.07, 5.42, 5.55, 5.36, 5.29, 5.58, 5.65, 5.57, 
5.53, 5.62, 5.29, 5.44, 5.34, 5.79, 5.1, 5.27, 5.39, 5.42, 5.47, 
5.63, 5.34, 5.46, 5.3, 5.75, 5.68, 5.85};
```

I could use `BoxWhiskerChart[y, "Outliers", BarOrigin -> Left]`, which works well. 
[image: output]
But if I also want the median line (or other features), there is a problem.
For example, using

```
BoxWhiskerChart[y, "Outliers", "Median", BarOrigin -> Left]
```

will give the following error message
[image: error]
It seems Mathematica only allows one `bwspec` specification, and my question is: is that possible to have multiple `bwspec`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In V10 the median marker is supplied by default, So the following will give you what you want.

```
BoxWhiskerChart[y, "Outliers", BarOrigin -> Left]
```

[image: basic-chart]

However, as Brett Champion has pointed out in his answer, to have more than one specification requires all but the first specification to given in a more complete form. This is discussed, perhaps not a clearly as it could be, in the documentation for [`BoxWhiskerChart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BoxWhiskerChart.html). Here is an example of a fancier customization.

```
BoxWhiskerChart[
  y, 
  {"Outliers", {"MedianMarker", None}, {"MeanMarker", .5, Black}, {"MeanDiamond", .5, Red}}, 
  BarOrigin -> Left]
```

[image: fancy-chart]

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer.

Answer (score 4):

Not presently, although you can add individual items:

```
BoxWhiskerChart[y, {"Outliers", {"MedianMarker", 1, Red}}, BarOrigin -> Left]
```

[image]

Comment: But technically that is not `bwspec` right?

Comment: It is, actually.  It's an example of the last form in the *bwspec* table: `{name, {elem1, val1, ...}, ...}`.

Comment: but then why I can't just use `"Mean"` or `"Median"`?

Answer (score 1):

The following form of *bwspec*  works in both **Version 9**:

```
BoxWhiskerChart[y, {{"Outliers"}}, BarOrigin -> Left]
```

[image]

and **Version 10:**

[image]

So does

```
BoxWhiskerChart[y, {"Median", {"Outliers"}}, BarOrigin -> Left]
(* same picture *)
```